# How can keep checked row selected during pagination in Yii?

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii, pagination

I am using pagination to view table rows. I want to select different rows from different pages and then submit the form.

But when I select different rows from a page and move to another page to select more then back to previous page again, I didn't find already checked row there.

Here is my code-

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $j=0;   
    foreach($datavalue as $datainarray)
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="item_id[<?php echo $j; ?>]" name="item_id[<?php echo $j; ?>]" 
                value="<?php echo $datainarray->attributes['item_id']; ?>">
            </td>

            <td><?php echo $datainarray->attributes['Name'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $j++;   
    }
    ?>
</table>

<?php
    $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
         'itemCount'=>$row_count,
         'pageSize'=>20,
         'maxButtonCount'=> 10,
         'nextPageLabel'=>'Next >>',
         'header' => '',
    ));     
?>
```

I have searched web to find a solution but I didn't find a suitable solution.

Hoping to find suitable solution from experts.

Thanks

Comment: you need to store the checked element details and then when the new page is loaded check whether any of the checked items is displayed then mark them again as checked

Comment: Would you please write the solution how you are thinking.

Comment: you need to share your paging logic and the html

Answer (score 0):

Store the Selected row id into array when the row is selected, when previous page is loaded then select those rows on the basis of array's values.